# Using exit status for ping command in a script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, ping

I have this scipt which should echo on exit status 0 of ping command `$HOST is reachable`, on exit status 1 `$HOST is unreachable` and when I insert some non existing URL to `HOST` variable it should echo `$HOST is unknown`, which is exit status 2 from ping command.

But I am getting echo **google.blahblah is unreachable** output for non existing URL.
What am I missing?

```
    #!/bin/bash

HOST="google.blahblah" 

ping -c 1 $HOST

if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]
then
    echo "$HOST is reachable."

elif [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]
then
    echo "$HOST is unreachable"

else 
    echo "$HOST is unknown." 
fi
```

In terminal it exits with status 2

```
adminuser@ubudesktop:~/scripts/lesson$ ping -c 1 google.blahblah ; echo $?
ping: google.blahblah: Name or service not known
2
```

Comment: ^that, which is explained nicely in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570356/70524

Comment: Please avoid using CAPS for variable names, that is bad practice since by convention, global environment variables are capitalized so if yours are also capitalized you can get weird bugs because of naming collisions.